# Does Amazon CloudWatch Logs support a newline character?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are aggregating our logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

We'd like to be able to append a **stack trace**. Does CloudWatch Log's web interface parse a newline character to make this more readable?

Comment: log4j2 [config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77686401/448078)

Answer (score 18):

I have faced a similar problem with logs for Lambda and I found two answers on the web that can be useful for anyone dealing with this.

1) For CloudWatch Logs Agent you could configure the
**multi_line_start_pattern** parameter (pointed by Greg [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=158643)).

2) On Lambda Logs you could use **\r** instead of **\n** as the new line delimeter (tested on 2017-05-30 only for lambda running python 2.7 with logging module)(pointed by RichardBronosky [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/296)).