# New line problem in CloudWatch output when logging with slf4j (and io.symphonia:lambda-logging) in AWS Lambas

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, slf4j, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the problem, that when logging with slf4j (and io.symphonia:lambda-logging) in Java, for every new line in the logging message CloudWatch outputs a new log message. This also happens for exceptions using the `LOGGER.error(String msg, Throwable t)`)

And since the messages output by CloudWatch are unsorted and multiple messages can come in from different Lambdas (or other Services, etc.) the logs are becoming unreadable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution to this is to setup the logging pattern in the logging configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration packages="com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2">
  <appender name="Lambda" class="io.symphonia.lambda.logging.DefaultConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %logger{0}:%line: %replace(%msg){'\n','&#xd;'} %replace(%exception){'\n','&#xd;'} %nopexception %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="Lambda" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

See the `<pattern>` tag: The magic is in the `%replace(%msg){'\n','&#xd;'}` and the `%replace(%exception){'\n','&#xd;'} %nopexception`. Both calls are replacing the new line (\n) with a carriage return () for the log message (%msg) and a passed in exception (%exception). The reason why the second argument is in Unicode Hex Character Code and the first isn't is described in the conversation on GitHub linked below.
I put this into a loggerconfig.xml and setup the logger to use it in the class that is the entry point for the lambda like this:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER;

  static {
    // must be set before the very first call to LoggerFactory.getLogger()
    System.setProperty(ContextInitializer.CONFIG_FILE_PROPERTY, "loggerconfig.xml");
    LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassThatShallLog.class);
  }
```

I came to this solution through [this](https://github.com/symphoniacloud/lambda-monitoring/issues/4) conversation on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi_line_start_pattern http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/AgentReference.html. 
You can set it to be your timestamp, in which case you will get the desired behavior:

Comment: How do you configure the cloudwatch agent for a lambda?

Comment: @ohshazbot I'm also looking for the same answer

Comment: I believe the answer is you can't and that this parent answer is not applicable to this question

Answer (score 0):

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5p | %.20t | %c{0}:%L | %replace{%m%n%xEx}{\r?\n}{&#xd;}%ex{none}%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.company.project" level="debug" />
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is the `slf4j-aws-lambda` logger.

This wraps LambdaLogger from `aws-lambda-java-core`. LambdaLogger has its own magic for handling newline characters. And it is smaller in comparison to `logback`.

**Update:**
If logback is your choice try [jlib AWS Lambda SLF4J/Logback Appender](https://github.com/jlib-framework/jlib-awslambda-logback)